# Understanding DAO-pattern and interfaces

Tags: java, interface, dao

I'm reading **`J. Bloch`**'s effective Java and he said the following:

> Once an interface is released and widely implemented, it is almost
>   impossible to change.

So, now consider the simple interface for [DAO-pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html):

```
public interface UserDao{

    public User getById(int id);

    public Collection<User> getAll();

    public boolean delete(int userId);

    public boolean update(User u);

}
```

This is how my `Dao` interface looked when it was released firstly. By the time, I had to add some functionality to users in order to aggregate all users by its `registration_date` or something similar. So, I needed to add  corresponding method declarations to the `DAO`-interface and implement it.

Moreover for now I can't imagine how `DAO`-interfaces may be more or less stable at all, because adding some new `DAO`-operations happens very often.

Maybe it's my DAO design disaster, or interfaces are hardly suitable for `DAO`s?

Comment: You can remove public keyword from your interface, cause they are redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that sentence of J. Bloch is meant to public interfaces, and not for your DAO case.

Think of you creating a public API to let any programmer use your platform. If you are changing that interface, your are requiring programmers to adapt his code, so this will be frustrating.

But if you are creating an interface for the purpose of your internal app, you are not assuming that risk, and it is worth to evolve your interface as you need.

Obviously you have to consider how many classes implements your interface and assume the cost of the modification.

Comment: *I think that sentence of J. Bloch is meant to public interfaces.* Agreed. Internal interfaces in a project change all the time.